# Enable multi-monitor expose?

Tags: release-freya, keyboard-shortcuts, display

Expose acts really weird on multiple monitors on Freya. On Luna, it worked great, but on Freya, there seems to have been a regression leading to only one monitor doing the expose:

[image]

Is there a way to re-enable expose for multiple monitors? To test the problem: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

At my PC the workspace switcher works just fine. Each monitor has their own workspaces. You might want to check your videocard drivers or [file an bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+filebug)

Update:
I've misunderstood your question. It doesn't seem that what you want is possible right now.

Comment: That's exactly what I _don't want_, I want all current active monitors to share the workspace, not maintain one workspace per monitor. If you do <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, you should see what I mean.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Ah okay, I thought the problem was that the second monitor was grey (which isn't the correct behavior). I've updated my answer.

Comment: The problem _is_ that the second monitor is grey when activating expose. I keep getting the feeling that elementary OS doesn't _believe_ in multiple monitors :-|

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Then you should file a bug report, because thats not how it should work. I have 2 monitors myself, and if I go to the workspace switcher, BOTH monitors have their own workspaces. If I go to monitor 1 and switch to workspace 2 that doesn't impact monitor 2. If on monitor 2 I go to workspace 2, that works just fine and doesn't impact monitor 1. Thats the intended method. There should be no grey screen whatsoever. You should file a report for the grey screen, and you could file a feature request for monitor-shared workspaces because thats not possible right now.